# How to resolve Invalid column index in JSP?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

When executing the code below in JSP, I'm getting the "Invalid Column Index" error.

```
<%
        int eno;
        String firstnm;
        String lastnm;
        String gen;
        int ph;
        String desig;
        Date dt;
        String dnm;

        String qry="select e.empid,fname,lname,gender,d.mobile,j.designation,j.doj,n.dname from emp_master e,emp_digital d,emp_job j,dept n where e.empid=d.eno and e.empid=j.eno and e.deptid=n.dno";

        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(qry);

          while(rs.next())
          {
            eno=rs.getInt(0);
            firstnm=rs.getString(1);
            lastnm=rs.getString(2);
            gen=rs.getString(3);
            ph=rs.getInt(2);
            desig=rs.getString(0);
            dt=rs.getDate(1);
            dnm=rs.getString(1);

            %>
         <tr bgcolor="#D4DFFF" >
             <td><% out.println(eno); %></td>
          <td ><% out.println(firstnm); %></td>
          <td><% out.println(lastnm); %></td>
          <td><% out.println(gen); %></td>
          <td><% out.println(ph); %></td>
          <td><% out.println(desig); %></td>
          <td><% out.println(dt); %></td>
          <td><% out.println(dnm); %></td>
        </tr>
       <%
        }
       %>
```

I have the following database:

```
Emp_master:

- EMPID Number primary key

- FNAME Varchar2

- LNAME Varchar2

- GENDER    Varchar2

- DOB   Date

- DEPTID    Number

Emp_digital:

- USERID varchar2 primary key

- PASSWORD  Varchar2

- MOBILE    number

- ENO   number foreign key

- DOB   Date

- DEPTID    Number

Emp_job:

- designation   varchar2

- doj   date

- salary    number

- Eno   primary key,foreign key

Dept:

- Dno   Number primary key

- DNAME Varchar2

- LOC   Varchar2
```

I have given the index number according to each table. But have no idea as to why is it giving Invalid Column Index error. I ran the SQL query in Oracle, and it's producing the desired output. So there is no error in the query I guess because it does fetch the result.

Comment: Hi, could you post your error?probably problem with the numbers you have set on methods rs.get... Try following with indexes in order 4,5,6,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have given the index number according to each table

The numbers in the calls to `getInt(...)`, `getString(...)` are not indexes according to each table.  They are the indexes among the list of all columns selected.  You're selecting 8 columns, and as they are numbered starting from 1, you need to use indexes 1 to 8.  See for example the [documentation for the `ResultSet.getInt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)).

So instead of writing

```
            eno=rs.getInt(0);
            firstnm=rs.getString(1);
            lastnm=rs.getString(2);
            gen=rs.getString(3);
            ph=rs.getInt(2);
            desig=rs.getString(0);
            dt=rs.getDate(1);
            dnm=rs.getString(1);
```

write

```
            eno=rs.getInt(1);
            firstnm=rs.getString(2);
            lastnm=rs.getString(3);
            gen=rs.getString(4);
            ph=rs.getInt(5);
            desig=rs.getString(6);
            dt=rs.getDate(7);
            dnm=rs.getString(8);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting the misconception. Error solved. It worked !